# What does a new Ubuntu user need to know about installing on an Acer Aspire a515-51g?

Tags: system-installation, uefi, acer

I am new to Linux based systems. My laptop hardware is i5-8250u 8gb ddr4 RAM MX150 ddr5 2gb GPU 1TB hdd.

I would like to know if Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will work fine on this setup.

Also, the seller installed Windows 10 on it. I think he fiddled with the BIOS and I used MBR partition for UEFI while writing the USB image for Ubuntu. Do I need to change anything in the BIOS before installing on it?

Comment: That should work fine with ubuntu, the graphics should work ootb with the open source drivers and everything else should be natively supported on the 4.15 kernel AFAIK.

If the seller changed the bios to legacy mode, you'd want to change that back to normal but otherwise I'm assuming you plan on wiping the disk so you can just change the partition table during installation.

Comment: Acer in UEFI mode require you to enable a UEFI password and set "trust" on the ubuntu .efi boot file(s).  If using UEFI you should use gpt partitioning. And better to use gpt even if using BIOS and keep ESP, so later you could convert to UEFI, if desired without having to totally reformat entire drive. Win10 default install should have been UEFI/gpt. Asus M32CD desktop - Skylake several boot parameters  pci=nomsi  i915.preliminary_hw_support=1
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2312977
& 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2307273

Comment: I didn't understand much of that. Like I said I am totally new to this. I am trying to learn about it. One thing tho, I tried ubuntu from the USB drive it seemed to work fine. Now my major concern is to keep the old partitions from win10 D and E drives and install ubuntu on the C drive while completely erasing win10. Also I checked that BIOS boot mode from msinfo32, it showed UEFI. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Reference:
[Acer A515-51G 15.6-inch Laptop | amazon.in](https://www.amazon.in/Acer-A515-51G-15-6-inch-i5-8250U-Integrated/dp/B079JWTY5X?tag=googinhydr18418-21)

Yes, this model support linux. Then it will sure support ubuntu.

For bios: Turn off uefi. Keep legacy mode. I had same problem in my acer laptop too. And i solved it by this.

Comment: I checked the BIOS boot mode from msinfo32 it showed UEFI. I would like to keep my D and E drives from win10 partition intact and would like to install ubuntu on the C drive while replacing win10.

Answer (score 0):

I have 18.04 installed via UEFI, and 16.04 (originally) on my desktop via UEFI boot.UEFI boot works fine with 16.04+